# Access 2007 Report Performance

Tags: sql-server, caching, report, ms-access-2007

So I am developing reports in Access 2007 that use pass-through queries to retrieve data from SQL server.  Some of the queries can take a second or two to run on the server side.  When opening a report, in preview mode, based on one of these queries, the time required to render the report is much longer than the time required to simply run the query.  I used SQL Profiler to watch what was happening and found that the underlying query is being executed multiple times (at least five) when the report runs.  How can I get Access to cache the query results to increase the performance of these reports?

Comment: Are there any User-Defined functions running against the results of this query? If not then I suggest creating a simple Access query which runs "SELECT * from passthroughqueryname" and then use this as the basis of your report as this may prevent Access from running it several times.

Comment: @Matt Thanks for the suggestion, but that didn't have any effect. FYI... the source for the pass-through query is a stored procedure, if that makes any difference.

Comment: That is a little strange, instead then (dependent on the amount of data the pass-thru query returns), I would suggest using a "Make Table" query from this pass-thru in order to store the results locally in an Access table, then bind the report to the local table. You could either "Drop" and "Re-create" the table each time you ran the procedure, or you could truncate the data and then just append from the pass-thru. *Not a method I like as the server is there to be utilised, but sometimes just the way it is*

Comment: UPDATE: We have migrated to Access 2010, which does not exhibit the above behaviour.